# request helper is null when use custom form request in lravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I Create Custom form request called CreatedAtFilterRequest. i add to this request like this:

```
 public function show(CreatedAtFilterRequest $request, $id)
{
    $wallet = Http::get($this->endpoint . "/test/{$id}")->json();

    $request->merge([
        'id' => $request['id'] ?? $id,
        'inline' => true,
    ]);

    dd(request()->all()); // this is null
    dd($reques->all()); // this is ok
}
```

why is `dd(request()->all()` null?

i need request facade in blade like this:

```
<input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" value="{{ request('id') }}">
```

but 'request('id')' is null.

Answer (score 0):

Look like merge request data is null .So you can do the following

```
 request()->merge([
        'id' => $request['id'] ?? $id,
        'inline' => true,
    ]);
```

If it had  `Request` instead of `CreatedAtFilterRequest`  then it woks.Looks like it treat `CreatedAtFilterRequest` instance is different then `Request` instance